# Premiere distorts 2.0 anamorphic R3D footage when paused in the source viewer

Tags: premiere, workflow, red

This is my first time working with anamorphic red footage. When I view footage in the source monitor, all anamorphic clips are sheared diagonally (image below):
[image]

The problem does not persist when the footage is playing back, or when I'm viewing it on the timeline, or through RED Player.

It only shears when paused within the source monitor, as well as viewing RED R3D Source settings. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have a similar issue with H.264 footage from a Canon 60D.

Comment: Could you put somewhere original footage, so we could mess around with it? I don't have R3D footage, so can't check if something works.

Answer (score 1):

Just finished working with exact same sort of footage. I never got that issue.

- Update Premiere CC.
- Start a new project from scratch. Import one R3D file and create a sequence from it. See what happens.
- Create a new project in another editing program, one that can read R3D footage. Create brand new sequence, see what happens.
- Try this solution: https://video.stackexchange.com/a/16246/11961